# symfony2 behind Amazon ELB: always trust proxy data?

Tags: symfony, proxy, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I'm running a Symfony2 web application on AWS, and am using an Elastic Load Balancer.

In a controller method, I need to do the following to get the IP of a user requesting a web page:

```php
$request->trustProxyData();
$clientIp = $request->getClientIp(True);
```

Does this present any security risks? I'm not using the client IP for privilege escalation, I'm just logging it.

Is there some way to force `trustProxyData()` always, or otherwise reconfigure `$request->getClientIp()` to [DWIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM)? My app will always be behind a load balancer (except while I do development on my desktop).

Related: http://fabien.potencier.org/article/51/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-2 (but it doesn't say if there's some global config so I don't have to call `trustProxyData()` everywhere).

Answer (score 4):

You can configure the framework bundle to do this: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/framework.html#trust-proxy-headers

```
framework:
    trust_proxy_headers: true
```

Comment: Is this secure?  Seems like a blanket trust is risky.  Is there a way to overwrite the default "X_FORWARDED_PROTO"with the one Amazon AWS load balancers use "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO".

Comment: Acyra: configure which proxies to trust http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/framework.html#trusted-proxies

Comment: This has changed (Symfony 2.3) as it needs to be: ```trusted_proxies:  [192.0.0.1, 10.0.0.0/8]``` - updating to use the IP CIDR range of the proxy. (see current [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#trusted-proxies))

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about any general security risks, but I can give you a tip how to avoid calling this method in each controller action.

In your `app.php` just before the `$kernel->handle(...);` you should set:

```
Request::trustProxyData();
```

---

Cheers ;)

Comment: This works best for Symfony 2.2 application when using with ELB, which has dynamic IPs and Symfony 2.2 doesn't support CIDR.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

The trust_proxy_headers option is deprecated and will be removed in Symfony 2.3.

See [a trusted_proxies](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/framework.html#trusted-proxies)  and [a Trusting Proxies](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/http_foundation/trusting_proxies.html) for details on how to properly trust proxy data.

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
Request::setTrustedProxies(array($request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')));
```

in `web/app.php` to solve the problem.

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28793609/2030937

Comment: Still works as of Symfony 3.4. My server is behind CloudFlare CDN with forced https redirect. Having a route with `schemes:    [https]` made me get 'TooManyRedirects'. However, adding this line in `web/app.php` did fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In modern symfony versions: https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html#but-what-if-the-ip-of-my-reverse-proxy-changes-constantly

If your elb is behind a cloudfront proxy you should take a look at this package too:
https://packagist.org/packages/fmaj/cloudfront-trusted-proxies