# Elastic Load Balancer with Symfony 2.1

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services

On symfony 2.1, there was an additional field `trusted_proxies`, to tell the framework which proxies it should trust. **Amazon's Elastic Load Balancer** tells you not to rely on the IP it's assigned, since it can change.

How do you set the `trusted_proxies` directive on such an environment? Currently I'm using `trust_proxy_data`, but it has been deprecated and is marked for removal in Symfony 2.3.

Comment: Have you checked this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957811/symfony2-behind-amazon-elb-always-trust-proxy-data?

Comment: As I stated, in Symfony 2.3 that directive is going to be removed. I'm currently using that solution, but I was searching if there was a better option.

Comment: Excuse me for my blindness :[

Comment: I am not an expert on AWS, but im pretty sure they offer you a DNS name that never changes for the load balancer, so you should use that name instead of the ip address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On symfony 2.2 they added the option to allow a range of IPs, which does solve this issue. Sadly on 2.1 you can only set `trusted_proxies` to true, letting all proxies modify the client IP.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on AWS, but im pretty sure they offer you a DNS name that never changes for the load balancer, so you should use that name instead of the ip address? Heres something interesting:
http://nickhills.com/wp/2012/02/aws-elastic-load-balancing-with-a-static-ip-address/

Comment: If I'm not wrong Symfony2 only allows you to give IPs to that array, no DNS names, though I'll check it. I'll also check the article to see if it can fix the issue at hand, and if so, mark your answer as valid.

Comment: Even if the config allows DNS names, it won't help. The IP addresses can and do change. Symphony can't constantly re-lookup the DNS name just in case it changes.